# How do I solve this: $a^{x^y}$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, exponentiation

> How do I solve this: $a^{x^y}$

I first evaluated the $x^y$ and then put the answer as an exponent of $a$.

I don't know if this is the right way to do it.

And also, what if the expression is like this: $a^{x^{y^z}}$ and so on...

Please help me out.

I am a beginner at Stack Exchange Math, so I don't know know how to format it. Kindly bear with it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: We solve an equation but we evaluate an expression. Please, precise the question and, by the way, *Welcome to the site !*

Comment: See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_exponential_function) for a discussion of $\displaystyle a^{b^c}$.